# How to populate two comboboxes with different DB table in VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net, combobox

im trying to populate 2 `ComboBox`es from two different database table, but my codes seems not working, what should i do here?

code:

```
Dim st As String = "server=localhost;user id=root;database=db;password=root"
    Dim con As New MySqlConnection(st)
    con.Open()
    Dim se As String = "select * FROM tbl1 as t1, tbl2 as t2 WHERE t1.col=t2.col"
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(se, con)
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    While dr.Read()

        ComboBox1.Items.Add(dr("col1"))
        ComboBox2.Items.Add(dr("col1"))
    End While
    con.Close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code creates a JOIN between the first table and the second table using the old-style join syntax that has been deprecated. You get just one result out of that command, there are no two tables. Please review the syntax used in [old style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) and the correct way to JOIN tables.

However, if you wish to set your combos with data coming from two different tables, without executing two different command, you could write

```
Dim st = "server=localhost;user id=root;database=db;password=root"
Dim cmdText = "select colFromTbl1 FROM tbl1; SELECT colFromTbl2 from tbl2"
Using con = New MySqlConnection(st)
Using cmd = New MySqlCommand(con, cmdText)
    con.Open()
    Using dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
      While dr.Read()
         ComboBox1.Items.Add(dr("colFromTbl1"))
      End While
      dr.NextResult()
      While dr.Read()
         ComboBox2.Items.Add(dr("colFromTbl2"))
      End While
    End Using
End Using
End Using
```